# Active when scrolled to its section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have this percentage progress bar active when the user have scrolled to its section, currently it moves as soon as you refresh the page or click on the url.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
  <path class="circle-bg"
    d="M18 2.0845
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
  />
  <path class="circle"
    stroke-dasharray="29, 100"
    d="M18 2.0845
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
  />
  <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">29%</text>
</svg>

.circular-chart {
 display: block;
 margin: 10px auto;
 max-width: 80%;
 max-height: 250px;
}

.circle-bg {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #eee;
 stroke-width: 3.8;
}

.circle {
 fill: none;
 stroke-width: 2.8;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
0% {
 stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
   }
 }

.circular-chart.orange .circle {
 stroke: #ea5031;
 }

.percentage {
 fill: #666;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-anchor: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check on event scroll of document (throttle it please) whether element top position is within visibility range of document scroll. If visible then add a class to the element that will initiate the animation.

css:

```css
.circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2.8;
    stroke-linecap: round;
}

.animated {
    animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}
```

js:

```js
var lastKnownScrollPosition;


function isScrolledIntoView(el, is_partially, tolerance) {
    if (el.length) {
        el = el[0]
    }
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemTop = rect.top;
    var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
    var isVisible
    if (is_partially) {
        isVisible = (elemTop < window.innerHeight - tolerance) && (elemBottom >= 0 + tolerance);
    } else {
        isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    }
    return isVisible;
}

function do_install_scroll_listener() {
    var ticking = false;
    lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    function foo_scroll() {
        lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
        if (!ticking) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                do_select_closest_video_to_play(YOUR_ELEMENT);
                ticking = false;
            });
            ticking = true;
        }
    }
    $(document).on('scroll', foo_scroll)
}

function do_select_closest_video_to_play(my_video_container) {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(my_video_container, true, 40)) {
        $(my_video_container).addClass("animated");
    }
}

do_install_scroll_listener();
```

## a working example

https://jsfiddle.net/itgoldman/kr13sjod/4/